# How to go about debugging PCB Power Supply Circuits to ensure correct output voltage?

Tags: power, pcb, converter, debugging, test

I'm currently soldering, testing and validating the components on this PCB that I designed a few months back. [image: PCB Printout]
As it is right now I have soldered the 1.2V, 2.5V, 3.3V and 5V buck converter power circuits and that schematic is shown below.[image: Power Supply Schematic]
I have done continuity tests to check for shorts, that passed, and also haven't found any solder bridges. After continuity testing, I decided to power it just to do some initial testing of the output voltages for each converter to make sure the power planes were getting the correct voltages.
This is the part I'm not fully understanding. When I check each output capacitor I get the same voltage as my Input Voltage (~15V).

I can't figure out if this means that every converter circuit is either designed poorly, soldered incorrectly, or an incorrect testing method. My current thought is that I'm completing the circuit from the power adapter, at my output capacitors, and reading the input voltage. That leads me to wonder if I need a load to test the output voltage correctly and how that could be implemented on a PCB that utilizes SMD components. If you have any suggestions I would appreciate it!

Comment: Ok that’s what I was thinking. I need to figure out how to go about attaching a load to the output. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: datasheet  shows efficiency with a 100uA load minimum

Answer (score 7):

You appear to have pin 2 and 3 swapped on your [TPS62120](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps62120.pdf) symbol.

Pin 2 should be ground.

Pin 3 should be enable.

Comment: Yup, that'll be problematic.

Comment: I’m not sure how I ended up with this pinout. Is there any realistic way to salvage this or would it require a respin with a corrected pinout?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to respin to correct this. While it's possible to rework a board it will be messy and fragile, not something you'd want to do on more than one board. And even though the TPS62101's likely survived this particular mis-wiring, the fact that all your rails output 15V very likely destroyed any chips they were connected to.

Comment: That’s what I figured, luckily I only soldered my power circuits so I could test and validate their outputs. I also noticed the TPS62101 takes a 15V max input and when I tested the input from my wall wart supply I found it outputted 15.3V. Is this possible to work with or should I drop the voltage before it makes it to the power circuits?

Comment: Well, the absolute max is 17V so you should be fine. And your wall wart will likely be closer to 15V or a little lower under full load.

Comment: @td127 Ok I thought I had read in the datasheet max 15V. Also I looked back at my simulations using the ti transient model given on the digikey page for the TPS6210. https://imgur.com/a/OR4THkp
This was the pinout used in the ti simulation on pspice. Not sure why they differ from simulation pinout to physical pinout listed in the datasheet.

Comment: 15V is the Recommended Operating Condition. But the Absolute Max is 17V so you're OK. If running that close to the edge makes you nervous, better to just change to a 12V wall wart rather than inserting components to drop down the 15V.

Comment: I have decided to redesign the power supply with options to bypass each power circuit if one or more fails (since this is a prototype). Right now I’m needing to go back through and determine the max requirement the wall wart power adapter will have to meet for each of the power circuits and I’m not sure the best way to do this, or really where to start. @td127 Got any suggestions?

Comment: The TPS62120 is pretty wimpy, limited to not much more than 50mA – is that enough? If so, you’re using very little power, less than a watt overall, so any wall wart from 9V to 15V will suffice. If your loads need more than 50mA you’ll need to find a beefier regulator.